# Caching Thrift Transports

Tags: thrift

I'm implementing service discovery for my Thrift application. Servers announce their address themselves to a known path in ZooKeeper, and clients maintain a local cache of this path which they use to dynamically route requests to server instances (similar to Curator Service Discovery).

Should each client also cache the `TTransport` required to connect to the physical servers? Doing so would allow me to avoid the cost of reopening a `TTransport` for subsequent requests on a server. However, I'm worried that caching the `TTransport` would mean that I would have to maintain an open connection to each server in my cluster, which could potentially degrade performance for both my clients and servers.

Is it safe to cache open `TTransport` connections, or is it better to renegotiate the connection each time a request is made?

Edit: [I went ahead and implemented service discovery with `TTransport` caching](https://github.com/ashwin153/caustic/blob/master/caustic-runtime/src/main/scala/caustic/runtime/service/Cluster.scala), but I'm still not sure if this is the right approach. Would love to know if this is the right way, or if there is a better solution out there.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't hold the connection open there is no point in caching TTransport instances.

Comment: What if I am holding the connection open?

Comment: You may want to close it later, so very likely you want to keep the pointer somewhere. Since we talk about caching (or pooling): be aware that some resources cannot be used across different threads due to underlying OS restrictions.

Comment: I'm aware that transports are not thread-safe, and so I'm synchronizing across threads. I'm more concerned with the potential performance impact of having a number of open transports. Do you know if that could be a problem for my client or my server?

Comment: Thrift acts a quite thin layer, so the *additional* overhead is low.I think the main issue may be OS resources used, but that's not specific to Thrift. A socket is a socket is a socket.